# Incorrect Syntax near Select

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       c.AUF_NR AS JPO,
       c.KUNR AS CustNo,
       c.BESTELL_NR AS CustJPO,
       c.KOPF_PROJEKT AS Project,
       c.ERFASS_DAT AS OrdDate,
       c.LIEFER_DAT AS DlvDate

FROM OPENQUERY (server,'
     server.AUF_STAT a,
     server.AUF_POS b,
     server.AUF_KOPF c
WHERE 
      c.AUF_NR = 140281')
```

Comment: SQL Server and Oracle? What Versions? Your OPENQUERY query should also start with SELECT 'SELECT LIORDER.AUF_STAT..' Your main query is not a subset of the openquery... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write as:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM OPENQUERY (server,' select DISTINCT   c.AUF_NR AS JPO,
                                c.KUNR AS CustNo,
                                c.BESTELL_NR AS CustJPO,
                                c.KOPF_PROJEKT AS Project,
                                c.ERFASS_DAT AS OrdDate,
                                c.LIEFER_DAT AS DlvDate
                        from 
                                --server.AUF_STAT a,
                                --server.AUF_POS b,
                                server.AUF_KOPF c
                        WHERE 
                                c.AUF_NR = 140281')
```

Answer (score 1):

The query that you're attempting to pass on to `server` is not complete. It has to be a proper SQL query, not just the final bit as you have.